# How fix Error "ReferenceError: emailSent is not defined" to send emails triggered by form submit?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

**I'm making a ticketing system where an email is sent to the caller and another sent to the person concerned. I'm new to AppScript and I just frankensteined this script from various sources. <strike>When I added the lines to prevent duplicates I get this error "ReferenceError: emailSent is not defined"</strike>

Now I get this error: *ReferenceError: sheet is not defined (line 45, file "Code")*

I do get the duplicate emails, so at least I know that works.

Here is my code, can someone help out please?**

(EDIT: 19 APRIL 2022)

var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails2() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

/*
Equivalent Column Of "var" Tags In Sheet: "Ticket Number".
(Prefixed with "*" are the info sent to the caller.)

1  - *Date: date
2  - *Ticket Number: ticket
5  - *Name of Caller: name
6  - Email Address: emailAddress (for emails to caller) and contactA (for emails to receiver)
7  - Other Contact Info: contactB
8  - *Application or Registration Number: appln
9  - *Title of the Mark: title
10 - *Mark Identifiers: identifier
11 - Who is the call for?: receiver
12 - ENTER THE DETAILS OF THE CONCERN HERE: concern
13 - What type of call is this?: type
14 - What was the caller's demeanor?: demeanor

The following code is to send an email to the caller.
All sensitive info is redacted from the email.
*/

```
var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Ticket Number');
var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Email Template');
var subject = sheet2.getRange(2,1).getValue();
var n=sheet1.getLastRow();
for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {
  var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i,6).getValue();
    var date=sheet1.getRange(i,1).getValue();
    var ticket=sheet1.getRange(i,2).getValue();
       var name=sheet1.getRange(i,5).getValue();
       var appln=sheet1.getRange(i,8).getValue();
       var title=sheet1.getRange(i,9).getValue();
       var identifier=sheet1.getRange(i,10).getValue();
  var message = sheet2.getRange(2,2).getValue();
message=message.replace("<date>",date).replace("<ticket>",ticket).replace("<name>",name).replace("<appln>",appln).replace("<title>",title).replace("<identifier>",identifier);
var emailSent =sheet1.getRange(i,15).getValue();
if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && emailAddress!="") {
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 15).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
```

//"EMAIL SENT" IN COLUMN 15 (LETTER O) IN "TICKET NUMBER" SHEET

/*
The following code is to send an email to the person or unit concerned.
All info from the form will be sent to the receiver.
*/

```
    var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Ticket Number');
    var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Email Template');
    var subject = sheet2.getRange(3,1).getValue();
    var n=sheet1.getLastRow();
    for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {
      var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i,3).getValue();
        var date=sheet1.getRange(i,1).getValue();
        var ticket=sheet1.getRange(i,2).getValue();
           var name=sheet1.getRange(i,5).getValue();
           var contactA=sheet1.getRange(i,6).getValue();
           var contactB=sheet1.getRange(i,7).getValue();
           var appln=sheet1.getRange(i,8).getValue();
           var title=sheet1.getRange(i,9).getValue();
           var identifier=sheet1.getRange(i,10).getValue();
           var receiver=sheet1.getRange(i,11).getValue();
           var concern=sheet1.getRange(i,12).getValue();
           var type=sheet1.getRange(i,13).getValue();
           var demeanor=sheet1.getRange(i,14).getValue();
      var message = sheet2.getRange(3,2).getValue();
    message=message.replace("<date>",date).replace("<ticket>",ticket).replace("<name>",name).replace("<contactA>",contactA).replace("<contactB>",contactB).replace("<appln>",appln).replace("<title>",title).replace("<identifier>",identifier).replace("<receiver>",receiver).replace("<concern>",concern).replace("<type>",type).replace("<demeanor>",demeanor);
    var emailSent =sheet1.getRange(i,15).getValue();
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && emailAddress!="") {
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 15).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
}
    }
    }
    }
}
```

Images as reference:
[Reference Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd3CR.jpg)
[Screenshot of Column for Email Sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIzFv.jpg)

Comment: Do you happen to have an `emailSent` column? I can't see the variable defined anywhere

Comment: You did not define emailsent variable it comes from column 15

Comment: I added the following:    **var emailSent =sheet1.getRange(i,15).getValue();
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && emailAddress!="") {
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 15).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);**      but I still get the same message, I guess I thought that this would update column 15 to populate with "email_sent" after the script runs and prevent it from resending. I guess I'm missing a step somewhere.

Comment: @sansushinjo Where exactly you added that ? What is textual error message? Please [edit] the question to update the script and the error message.

Comment: I did the edit on the question as asked. I hope the question looks clearer. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's finally working as intended.

The project goals were:

1. Collect data from a Google Form
2. Send this data to  Google Sheets
3. Generate a ticket number starting from 1 each day
4. Send a customized email to the caller
5. Send a customized email to the person concerned
6. Trigger to send emails upon every new form submitted
7. Do not send duplicate emails after initial emails were sent to the caller and person concerned

Note: I still get this error message via email notification: *Exception: Invalid email:*    but since everything else works I can just filter these messages in Gmail to be deleted.

Here was the successful code:

```
    var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";
    
    function sendEmails2() {
    
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

/*
Equivalent Column Of "var" Tags In Sheet: "Ticket Number".
(Prefixed with "*" are the info sent to the caller.)

1  - *Date: date
2  - *Ticket Number: ticket
5  - *Name of Caller: name
6  - Email Address: emailAddress (for emails to caller) and contactA (for emails to receiver)
7  - Other Contact Info: contactB
8  - *Application or Registration Number: appln
9  - *Title of the Mark: title
10 - *Mark Identifiers: identifier
11 - Who is the call for?: receiver
12 - ENTER THE DETAILS OF THE CONCERN HERE: concern
13 - What type of call is this?: type
14 - What was the caller's demeanor?: demeanor

The following code is to send an email to the caller.
All sensitive info is redacted from the email.
*/

//"EMAIL SENT" IN COLUMN 15 (LETTER O) IN "TICKET NUMBER" SHEET FOR CALLERS

var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Ticket Number');
var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Email Template');
var subject = sheet2.getRange(2,1).getValue();
var n=sheet1.getLastRow();
for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {
  var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i,6).getValue();
    var date=sheet1.getRange(i,1).getValue();
    var ticket=sheet1.getRange(i,2).getValue();
       var name=sheet1.getRange(i,5).getValue();
       var appln=sheet1.getRange(i,8).getValue();
       var title=sheet1.getRange(i,9).getValue();
       var identifier=sheet1.getRange(i,10).getValue();
  var message = sheet2.getRange(2,2).getValue();
message=message.replace("<date>",date).replace("<ticket>",ticket).replace("<name>",name).replace("<appln>",appln).replace("<title>",title).replace("<identifier>",identifier);
var emailSent =sheet1.getRange(i,15).getValue();
if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && emailAddress!="") {
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
sheet1.getRange(i, 15).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);

/*
The following code is to send an email to the person or unit concerned.
All info from the form will be sent to the receiver.
*/

//"EMAIL SENT" IN COLUMN 16 (LETTER P) IN "TICKET NUMBER" SHEET FOR PERSON CONCERNED

        var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Ticket Number');
        var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Email Template');
        var subject = sheet2.getRange(3,1).getValue();
        var n=sheet1.getLastRow();
        for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {
          var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i,3).getValue();
            var date=sheet1.getRange(i,1).getValue();
            var ticket=sheet1.getRange(i,2).getValue();
               var name=sheet1.getRange(i,5).getValue();
               var contactA=sheet1.getRange(i,6).getValue();
               var contactB=sheet1.getRange(i,7).getValue();
               var appln=sheet1.getRange(i,8).getValue();
               var title=sheet1.getRange(i,9).getValue();
               var identifier=sheet1.getRange(i,10).getValue();
               var receiver=sheet1.getRange(i,11).getValue();
               var concern=sheet1.getRange(i,12).getValue();
               var type=sheet1.getRange(i,13).getValue();
               var demeanor=sheet1.getRange(i,14).getValue();
          var message = sheet2.getRange(3,2).getValue();
        message=message.replace("<date>",date).replace("<ticket>",ticket).replace("<name>",name).replace("<contactA>",contactA).replace("<contactB>",contactB).replace("<appln>",appln).replace("<title>",title).replace("<identifier>",identifier).replace("<receiver>",receiver).replace("<concern>",concern).replace("<type>",type).replace("<demeanor>",demeanor);
        var emailSent =sheet1.getRange(i,16).getValue();
        if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && emailAddress!="") {
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
        sheet1.getRange(i, 16).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
    }
        }
        }
        }
    }
```

I showed this to IT and they helped me fix it. Thanks IT!